# Downloading from a cPanel server using cPanel credentials in FTP

Tags: php, curl, ftp, cpanel

I am in a situation where I have a list of around 50 accounts and there credentials in a csv like:

```
cpuser,cppassword,cpdomain,filename-for-download.tgz
```

- All files are located in `HOME` directory (not `public_html`) of each user
- Most of the domains `cpdomain` are not active (NS changed)
- I am able to login via `SFTP` from my ftp clients using these credentials
- Server uses default `FTP port 21`

I tried using a php script which uses the above credentials and `cURL` to the files like:

```
$url = 'ftp://CP.SERVER.IP/filename-for-download.tgz';
$fp  = fopen('filename-downloaded.tgz', 'w');

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$cpuser}:{$cppassword}");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

curl_exec($curl);
```

And what I get is a `0 byte` file which is indeed created only by the `fopen`

The response from `curl_getinfo()` is:

```
Array
(
    [url] => ftp://CP.SERVER.IP/filename-for-download.tgz
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 421
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.516362
    [namelookup_time] => 0.039582
    [connect_time] => 0.276871
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )
    [primary_ip] => REMOTE_SERVER_IP
    [primary_port] => 21
    [local_ip] => LOCAL_SERVER_IP
    [local_port] => 57659
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong, and what I should do alternatively.

I also thought about **moving** files to respective `public_html` and then `wget http://CP.SERVER.IP/~cpuser/filename-for-download.tgz`, but again this (`~username`) access is not enabled on the server.